# Excel Macro giving circular reference error

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am new to Macros below is what I wrote to be able to do a lookup through a function. When I debug all the values seem to work well except that at the end it gives error about circular reference.

I am making a call to below like: = GetCost("abc")

```
Public Function GetCost(arg1 As String)
'
' GetCost Macro
'
    Dim fName As String
    Dim searchItem As String
    Dim result As Integer

    fName = Range("B4").Value
    searchItem = Chr(34) & arg1 & Chr(34)

    expression = "=VLOOKUP(" & searchItem & "," & fName & ", 2, FALSE)"

    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate(expression)
    result = Evaluate(expression)

    GetBOMCOst = result

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The circular reference is because you are trying to change the value of the cell containing the function:

- remove ActiveCell.Value = ...
- change result= Evaluate to result =application.caller.parent.Evaluate(expression)

Also fName=Range("B4").value should use a fully qualified reference (Sheet.Range)

And this function should be made volatile otherwise it will not recalculate whenever the value in Range("B4") changes

Comment: How to make it volatile

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your active cell reference as suggested by other.

Also, its looks like, your lookup range is incorrect. Change the lookup expression as below, in case, if you have your value in A and B column.

```
expression = "=VLOOKUP(" & searchItem & "," & "A:B" & ", 2, FALSE)"
```

And, it looks like you trying to return the value to your calling function. In VBA, to return a variable, you need to assign the variable to a function name. i.e. change your last line `GetBOMCOst = result` to `GetCost = result`

Try the below updated version of the code.

```
Public Function GetCost(arg1 As String) ' ' GetCost Macro ' Dim fName As String Dim searchItem As String Dim result As Integer

searchItem = Chr(34) & arg1 & Chr(34)

expression = "=VLOOKUP(" & searchItem & "," & "A:B" & ", 2, FALSE)"

result = Evaluate(expression)

GetCost = result
End Function
```

Comment: Cell B4 has whole path that gets stored in 'fName'